# Texture mapping in X3dom

Tags: x3dom

I have been trying to work on this small university project and I am kind of stuck with the last bit of it. Wondering if any one can help me out here? I'll post the details below.
I am suppose to texture the shell of a turtle in this format (picture) [turtle shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRIz9.png), but I am unable to do so with the second hald of it (the pink part). All I got to is this [turtle i created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOkDh.png)... The codes are as below...

`

```
 6 7 12 -1
 7 8 12 -1
 8 9 12 -1
 9 10 12 -1
 10 11 12 -1
 11 6 12 -1


 0 1 14 13 -1
 1 2 15 14 -1
 2 3 16 15 -1
 3 4 17 16 -1
 4 5 18 17 -1
 5 0 13 18 -1

 14 13 19 -1
 14 15 19 -1
 15 16 19 -1
 16 17 19 -1
 17 18 19 -1
 18 13 19 -1
                                                 '
texCoordIndex=' 0 1 2 3 -1
0 1 2 3 -1
0 1 2 3 -1
0 1 2 3 -1
0 1 2 3 -1
0 1 2 3 -1

0 1 2 -1
0 1 2 -1
0 1 2 -1
0 1 2 -1
0 1 2 -1
0 1 2 -1

0 1 2 3 -1
0 1 2 3 -1
0 1 2 3 -1
0 1 2 3 -1
0 1 2 3 -1
0 1 2 3 -1

0 1 2 -1
0 1 2 -1
0 1 2 -1
0 1 2 -1
0 1 2 -1
0 1 2 -1'>

<Coordinate point='


0.866 0 0.5
0 0 1
-0.866 0 0.5
-0.866 0 -0.5
0 0 -1
0.866 0 -0.5


0.433 0.25 0.25
0 0.25 0.5
-0.433 0.25 0.25
-0.433 0.25 -0.25
0 0.25 -0.5
0.433 0.25 -0.25

0 0.5 0

0.433 -0.25 0.25
0 -0.25 0.5
-0.433 -0.25 0.25
-0.433 -0.25 -0.25
0 -0.25 -0.5
0.433 -0.25 -0.25


0 -0.5 0


             ' />
<TextureCoordinate point='
0.5 0.25,  
0.375 0.466, 
0.125 0.466, 
0 0.25, 
0 0.033, 
0.375 0.033'/> 
</IndexedFaceSet>
<Appearance>
<Material diffuseColor='0.5 1 0.5'/>
</Appearance>

</Shape>`
```

would really appreciate you help on this.

Comment: this is the start of the code.. for some reason it was omitted from the question itself                                                                                           <IndexedFaceSet solid='false'
              coordIndex=' 
                           0 1 7 6 -1
                           1 2 8 7 -1
                           2 3 9 8 -1
                           3 4 10 9 -1
                           4 5 11 10 -1
                           5 0 6 11 -1

Comment: I don't have specific knowledge of this language and I personally think you ould be better off asking your fellow students or professor for help.  Having said that, from what I am seeing you only need to calculate the coordinates of the hexagonal center, draw the hexagonal center and adjust the vertices now colliding in the center to go to the corners of the hexagonal.